# solr not searching in multi language

Tags: apache, solr, full-text-search

This is my schema.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- multi language in single core R&D Pallav Jha  -->
<schema name="Pallav" version="1.14">
  <uniqueKey>SolrId</uniqueKey>
  <defaultSearchField>Name</defaultSearchField>
  <solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR"/>
  <fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true"/>
  <fieldType name="booleans" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true"/>
  <fieldType name="date" class="solr.TrieDateField" positionIncrementGap="0" precisionStep="6"/>
  <fieldType name="float" class="solr.TrieFloatField" positionIncrementGap="0" precisionStep="0"/>
  <fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0" precisionStep="0"/>
  <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" positionIncrementGap="0" precisionStep="0"/>
  <fieldType name="nGramAttributes" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="!!.*?!!" replacement=""/>
      <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
      <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" maxGramSize="10" minGramSize="1"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.FrenchLightStemFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="French" />
      <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
      <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="German2"/>
      <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.FrenchLightStemFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="French" />
      <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="nGramtext" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
      <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" maxGramSize="15" minGramSize="3"/>
      <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.PhoneticFilterFactory" encoder="Soundex" inject="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.FrenchLightStemFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="French" />
      <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.PhoneticFilterFactory" encoder="Soundex" inject="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.FrenchLightStemFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="French" />
      <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" omitNorms="true" sortMissingLast="true"/>
  <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
      <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.PhoneticFilterFactory" encoder="Soundex" inject="true"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.PhoneticFilterFactory" encoder="Soundex" inject="true"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="textSpell" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <field name="SolrId" type="string" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="Name" type="string" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true"/> 

  <field name="en_Name" type="string" indexed="true" required="false" stored="true"/>
  <field name="nl_Name" type="string" indexed="true" required="false" stored="true"/>
  <field name="fr_Name" type="string" indexed="true" required="false" stored="true"/>
  <field name="hi_Name" type="string" indexed="true" required="false" stored="true"/> 

  <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="nGramContent" type="nGramtext" multiValued="true" indexed="true" required="false" stored="false"/>
  <dynamicField name="CDO_*" type="int" indexed="true" required="false" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="MDO_*" type="int" indexed="true" required="false" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="pa_*" type="string" multiValued="true" indexed="true" required="false" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="cp_*" type="string" indexed="true" required="false" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="f_*" type="string" multiValued="true" indexed="true" required="false" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_s" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <!-- <copyField source="Name" dest="SpellContent"/> -->

</schema>
```

I am trying to implement multi Language search for french only for testing.
but its not working i am not getting any result.Can any one help me.What i am doing wrong

This is my result for french.[solr french search result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qzmuy.png)

Comment: okay, in an english example you're doing just return all, could you try same on french?

Comment: this is my query for searching in french localhost:8983/solr/MultiLang/select?fq=fr_Name:A*&indent=on‌​&q=*:*&wt=json its giving me no result

Comment: i assume you have some data with name starting from A, right?:)

Comment: actually i want this record which i stored in french my query is that
http://localhost:8983/solr/MultiLang/select?fq=fr_Name:Apple%20MacBook%20Pro%2013%20pouces&indent=on&q=*:*&wt=json

Comment: plz update the question with intended query

Comment: i updated my question with query

Comment: i updated with new query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this fieldtype

```
<fieldType name="text_fr" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ElisionFilterFactory" articles="lang/contractions_fr.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" format="snowball" words="lang/stopwords_fr.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.FrenchLightStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

its working for me

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that field `fr_Name` is of type `string`, which means that it's not analyzed or tokenized, that if you want to search something which contains spaces, like `Apple Mac Book Pro`, you need to use double quotes, for a complete match. So, query `"fq":"fr_Name":\"Apple Mac Book Pro\"` should work for you.

Some reference material from the Solr wiki:

> String (UTF-8 encoded string or Unicode). Strings are intended for
>   small fields and are not tokenized or analyzed in any way. They have a
>   hard limit of slightly less than 32K.

Comment: by using this i am getting all the result i want only fr_Name:Apple Mac Book result

Comment: now, it depends on your data, did you get what i wrote to you? the string field is not analyzed, not tokenized, to get a match you need to write it fully in double quotes

Comment: in Solr Admin it could be possible, that you do not need to escape double quotes

Comment: actually i am implementing multi language search for french and dutch so its not giving me expected result

Comment: than your question is incorrect, since you never mention intended result

Comment: i need help for multi langauge search with solr

Comment: show how it looks like, when you try something with quotes